# Lighttpd returning from curl rather than nginx

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nginx, lighttpd

I have been having issues with being able to reach my websites hosted on my Raspberry Pi on my home network. It was all working until recently and I can't work out what I've done to break things :(
If I run `curl -I sarahcorballis.com` from the Pi (i.e. from the same machine the server is hosted on), or anywhere else, I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://sarahcorballis.com/
Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2021 07:45:43 GMT
Server: lighttpd
```

However, if I run `curl -I localhost` (or localhost:80), from the Pi I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2021 07:57:05 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3801
Last-Modified: Mon, 22 Apr 2019 18:39:21 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5cbe0a59-ed9"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The site is, indeed, hosted on nginx so I would expect to see `Server: nginx/1.14.2` on all requests. I'm wondering if `Server: lighttpd` is just a red herring or if it does, indeed imply something?

The network setup I have is Internet -> ISP provided router -> ASUS RX88U -> Raspberry Pi

Both the ISP router and the ASUS router have port forwarding 80-80 and 443-443 and the logs on both show no issues.

Until yesterday even the curl -I localhost threw up the lighttpd response so I think it's something somewhere in the Raspberry Pi but I'm flummoxed.

Here is the output of `ufw status`:

```
ERROR: Couldn't determine iptables version
```

Here is `iptables-save` output:

```
iptables-save/1.8.2 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported
```

So, that's another change from yesterday. So, what has changed? Well, I have upgraded from stretch to buster.

Comment: So the ufw and iptables issues were solved with a simple reboot. The other issues remain as is :(

Answer (score 1):

So, this is now solved.
In case anyone has a similar set up and encounters the same issue in the future the problem was I'd deleted a third site (didn't need it anymore); however, that site had the ssl certs which covered all three sites and were now gone. Worse, I'm not using Letsencrypt but instead am using Cloudflare origin certificates with HSTS to ensure more robust security. Cloudflare was causing the redirect that was then failing due to there being no certificate. I have now adopted a system of one certificate per site (lesson learned there).

Solution:

1. Generate a new certificate - one for each site
2. Save the certificates (both pem and key) to directories on the server
3. Amend the server blocks in nginx (/etc/nginx/sites-enabled) to point at the right directories and ensure http2 is enabled
4. Ensure SSL Strict selected in Cloudflare.

Here's the nginx config block for one of the sites:

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/<website>.com:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name sarahcorballis.com www.<website>.com;
    return 302 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {

    # SSL Configuration for Cloudflare 

    listen 443 ssl http2; 
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/<website>.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/<website>.com.key;

    server_name <website>.com www.<website>.com; 

    root /var/www/sarahcorballis.com/;

    index index.html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html ;


    client_max_body_size 50m;
}
```

You'd need to change  to whatever the website is you have and make sure that the suffix is the same as yours, if you happened to copy the block above.